# Delete Data from Room

Tags: android

I want to delete a projekt from the projekt table

here is the structure of the entire database

here is the structure of the entire database
the database consists of three tables and the notes table is referenced to the other two tables

```
`@Entity(tableName = "projekte")
data class Projekt(@PrimaryKey val id: Long, var beschreibung: String?) {
    fun getDescription(): String {
        val dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.SHORT) // Import!!
        val dateString = dateFormat.format(id)
        return if (beschreibung.isNullOrEmpty()) dateString else "$beschreibung ($dateString)"
    }
}

@Entity (tableName = "locations", primaryKeys = ["latitude", "longitude"])
data class Location(val latitude: Double, val longitude: Double,
val altitude: Double, val provider: String)

@VersionedParcelize
@Entity (tableName = "notizen",
    foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(entity = Projekt::class,
    parentColumns = ["id"], childColumns = ["projektId"]),
        ForeignKey(entity = Location::class, parentColumns = ["latitude", "longitude"],
            childColumns = ["latitude", "longitude"])])
data class Notiz(@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Long? = null,
val projektId: Long,
val latitude: Double,
val longitude: Double,
var thema: String,
var notiz: String):Parcelable {
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
        parcel.readValue(Long::class.java.classLoader) as? Long,
        parcel.readLong(),
        parcel.readDouble(),
        parcel.readDouble(),
        parcel.readString().toString(),
        parcel.readString().toString()
    ) {
    }

    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeValue(id)
        parcel.writeLong(projektId)
        parcel.writeDouble(latitude)
        parcel.writeDouble(longitude)
        parcel.writeString(thema)
        parcel.writeString(notiz)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<Notiz> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): Notiz {
            return Notiz(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Notiz?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}

@Database(entities = [Projekt::class, Notiz::class, Location::class], version = 1)
abstract class GeoNotesDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    companion object {
        private var INSTANCE: GeoNotesDatabase? = null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): GeoNotesDatabase {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context, GeoNotesDatabase::class.java, "GeoNotesDatabase").build()
            }
            return INSTANCE as GeoNotesDatabase
        }
    }
    abstract fun projekteDao(): ProjekteDao
    abstract fun locationDao(): LocationDao
    abstract fun notizenDao(): NotizenDao
}
@Dao interface ProjekteDao {
    @Insert (onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertProjekt (projekt: Projekt): Long

    @Query("SELECT * FROM projekte")
    fun getProjekte() : List<Projekt>

    @Query ("SELECT * FROM projekte where id=:id")
    fun getProjekt(id: Long): Projekt

    @Query ("DELETE FROM projekte where id= :id")
    fun deleteProjekt(id: Long?)

    @Update
    fun updateProjekt(projekt: Projekt)
}

@Dao interface LocationDao {
    @Insert (onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insertLocation(location: Location): Long

    @Query ("SELECT * FROM locations")
    fun getLocations(): List<Location>
}

@Dao interface NotizenDao {
    @Insert (onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertNotiz(notiz: Notiz): Long

    @Query ("SELECT * FROM notizen where projektId = :projektId")
    fun getNotizen(projektId: Long): List<Notiz>

    @Query ("SELECT * FROM notizen where projektId = :projektId AND id < :notizId ORDER BY id ASC")
    fun getPreviousNotizen(notizId: Long?, projektId: Long): List<Notiz>

    @Query ("SELECT * FROM notizen where projektId = :projektId AND id > :notizId ORDER BY id ASC")
    fun getNextNotizen(notizId: Long?, projektId: Long): List<Notiz>

    @Query ("SELECT * FROM notizen where id = :id")
    fun getNotiz(id: Long?): Notiz

    @Query("DELETE FROM notizen where id = :id")
    fun deleteNotiz(id: Long?)
}`
```

here is the code of the method to delete the notes and the projects the notes are successfully deleted but the project is not removed from the database after deleting the last note

```
` `fun notizLoeschen() {
        //Notiz Löschen
        val textViewThema = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.edittext_thema)
        val textViewNotiz = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.edittext_notiz)
        var notizen: List<Notiz>? = null
        if (aktuelleNotiz == null) return
        val database = GeoNotesDatabase.getInstance(this)
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                notizen = database.notizenDao().getNotizen(aktuellesProjekt.id)
            }

            if (notizen?.size!! > 1) {
                withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    database.notizenDao().deleteNotiz(aktuelleNotiz!!.id)
                }
                aktuelleNotiz = null
                textViewThema.text = ""
                textViewNotiz.text = ""
                return@launch

            }else {
                with(AlertDialog.Builder(this@GatherActivity)) {
                    setTitle("Löschen der letzten Notiz löscht das Projekt. Forfahren?")
                    setPositiveButton("OK", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, id ->
                        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {

                            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                                aktuelleNotiz = notizen!!.last()
                                Log.d(javaClass.simpleName, "TEST P: ${aktuelleNotiz?.id} P: ${aktuellesProjekt.id}") // Testweise eine Ausgabe der beiden ID's
                                database.notizenDao().deleteNotiz(aktuelleNotiz!!.id)
                                database.projekteDao().deleteProjekt(aktuellesProjekt!!.id)
                                aktuellesProjekt = Projekt(Date().time, "")
                                database.projekteDao().insertProjekt(aktuellesProjekt)

                            }
                        }
                        aktuellesProjekt = Projekt(Date().time, "")
                        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview_aktuelles_projekt).text = getString(R.string.aktuelles_projekt_prefix) + aktuellesProjekt.getDescription()
                        aktuelleNotiz = null
                        textViewThema.text = ""
                        textViewNotiz.text = ""

                    })
                    setNegativeButton(
                        "ABBRECHEN",
                        DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, id -> })
                    show()
                }
            }
        }

    }`
```

`

Answer (score 0):

```
@Dao 
interface ProjekteDao {
   @Delete
   fun delete(projekt: Projekt) <--- Add
}
```

`@Delete` will delete the exact object which is stored in the db with the same values.

Comment: thanks for the tip, unfortunately it doesn't work for me, the project remains in the database, only the note is deleted

Comment: Get the project you want from the DB and then pass that project you got from the Db to delete()